# Retrieving data from database to label in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[List Of Errors are Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYLZt.png) I have used this code to retrieve data from my database but when I run it, the label doesn't display the name of the user. I also try to get data from other forms, but still it remains the same.

Is something wrong with the code? Thank you..

```
  SqlConnection _sqlcnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MELIODAS;Initial Catalog=PROJECT;Integrated Security=True");    //SQL Connection Established
        _sqlcnn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader _reader = null;
            SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("select FNAME from LOGINFORM where Username=@USERNAME", _sqlcnn);

            SqlParameter _param = new SqlParameter();
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", "_FNAME");
            _param.ParameterName = "@USERNAME";
            _param.Value = _FNAME;
            _cmd.Parameters.Add(_param);

            _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();         //for displaying users name in the label
            if (_reader.Read())
            {
                _lblname.Text = _reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: `_lblname.Text = _FNAME;` of course this will always be the same. you probably meant `_lblname.Text = _reader.GetString(0);`

Comment: You didn't add the params.  `SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
   param.ParameterName = "@USERNAME";
   param.Value         = _FNAME; _cmd.Parameters.Add(param);`

Comment: I still get the same error sir

Comment: What is the error?You will have to set the userName value

Comment: sir Rakib the username variable/textbox is on the other form so, instead of username should i go for _FNAME

Comment: yes use `_FNAME`. I have posted it as a answer. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

1) You declared a parameter `@USERNAME` for your sql command, but did not pass this parameter:

```
SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("select FNAME from LOGINFORM where Username=@USERNAME", _sqlcnn);

// add username parameter value
// assuming _FNAME is the username you want to pass
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", _FNAME);
```

2) You don't read the value from the `SqlDataReader`:

```
_reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (_reader.Read())
    _lblname.Text = _reader.GetString(0); // read db value
```

I use only `if` instead of `while` because it seems you're only interested in the first (and probably single) row.

Comment: Sir "yourUserName" is it _FNAME? or another variable name?

Comment: @Gab I edited already, yes it is `_FNAME` if that's the variable where you store the username you want to use in this query.

Comment: **which** error? and did you debug? Is the expected name in `_FNAME` when you run it, and is there a row with that `Username` in your database?

Comment: Sir I already edited the whole code at the top and the errors is

Comment: yes there is a row on every username entry and i should display their first names

Answer (score 0):

Please add the param @USERNAME into command:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(); 
param.ParameterName = "@USERNAME"; 
param.Value = _FNAME;  

_cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```